# PHP: how to send push notifications to Apple device

Tags: php, ios, zend-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Our iOS app should receive push notification. Following [this](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/push-notifications-tutorial-for-ios-9/) tutorial I implemented these methods in application delegate:

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

and

`didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`

which are called by `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and it seems that the device is correctly registered in our MySQL service. Moreover, I have just created a pem sandbox certification that I will use for testing. Now, I need to know what I should do at the backend in PHP. Which code is required? We are using Zend framework so I should implement `function preparetosend_apple()`in my mapper and `sendtoappleAction()` in our controller but I don't know where to start from and how to test it. Thank you!

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mobile.push.apns.html

Comment: Thank you pal, I will have a look at once!

Answer (score 0):

First thing is sending push notification directly from application is not a good idea as this call can be blocking one (means the rest of the codeblock will wait for its completion). So I suggest using background processor/message queuing services (like gearman, zero mq, etc.).

Secondly easiest solution will be using [Parse](http://parse.com) like services. Parse allows registering the app using the certificates you mentioned and has SDK for php (composer based).

In the background service you just call the API from SDK. Like:

```
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParsePush;

ParseClient::initialize($appId, $restKey, $masterKey, $curlDebug);
...
...
...
```

Using channel in parse

```
$response = ParsePush::send(array(
                            "channels" => ["channel-$userId"],
                            "data"     => $data,
                           ));
```

OR using custom query

```
$query = ParseInstallation::query();
$query->equalTo('userId', "user-$userId");

$response = ParsePush::send(array(
                            "where" => $query,
                            "data"  => $data,
                           ));
```

The best part of using parse - I will say using other interesting features like -- broadcast messages, device listings, etc.

Hope this may help you.